# PHP : How to "null" a class result

Tags: php, function, class

I got a function which looks like that:

```
class ProcessFile {
    function Function1() {
        ...
    }
    function Function2() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I would like to use that function only if the file extension is not 'pdf':

```
if (substr(strrchr(strtolower($filename),'.'),1) != 'pdf') {
   $file = new ProcessFile($filename);
} else {
   $file = null; // Just a test
}
```

My concern is that later on the page, I call some functions like that at many places:

```
if (!empty($file->Function1())) {
   $var = $file ->Function1();
}
```

Which throws a error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   Function1() on null

I would like to avoid making all the calls in the first "if" test. How can I "null" the result of ProcessFille or check the member function exists before reading it?

Comment: `if ($file !== null)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [is_object()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php) in your if statement:

```
if (is_object($file)) {
   $var = $file ->Function1();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isset($file)` for checking that `$file` is not null:

```
if (isset($file)) {
   $var = $file ->Function1();
}
```